# How to get a js file path in iOS?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, copy

I dragged and dropped a .js file in to my project. I want to load it, but it's not working. It gives me a null path .

This is the first I try to get the path

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SearchWebView" ofType:@"js"];
```

this is not working. So then I think I might need to copy it in Documents/

So I run the copy file

```
- (NSString *)getJSFilePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SearchWebView.js"];
}

- (void) copyJSFileIfNeeded{
    //Using NSFileManager we can perform many file system operations.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *jsPath = [self getJSFilePath];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:jsPath]; 

    if(!success) {
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SearchWebView.js"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:jsPath error:&error];
        if (!success){ 
            //NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    [self performSelector:@selector(copyJSFileIfNeeded)];

}
```

It's not creating a new copy file in my documents folder. I don't know why?
I can use the same method to copy plist or sqlite file, But the ".js file" is no response .
I also check the file is exactly in my project bundle .

[image]

Comment: Delete "SearchWebView.js" in your project and again drag your file into your project and check option to "copy that file into destination folder".

Comment: Why trying to copy the file if `!success` ??

Comment: @Vince because I don't know why the file I can't get in main bundle ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you add the JavaScript file, Xcode detects that the file is a source code file, assumes you want to compile it and automatically adds it to the **Compile Sources** build phase.

To stop Xcode trying to compile it and make it copy the file instead, expand your target in the Groups and Files list, remove the JavaScript file from the **Compile Sources** build phase and add it to the **Copy Bundle Resources** build phase.

For Xcode 4, click on the main project, click on Build Phases, and you'll find **Compile Sources** and **Copy Bundle Resources**, detailed steps below -

1. Project Navigator (Cmd + 1)
2. Select your project
3. Select target
4. Select "Build Phases" tab, there you will get your desire sections.
5. Add desired js file to copy bundle resources and remove from compile sources

Comment: @AnilKothari,glad to help. If my answer has helped you please upvote :)

Comment: i have already done that. I know how to appreciate good work at stackOverflow.com

Comment: After flow your solution , and rebuild the project , I got the path
:-)
Thank you so much !!!